# Automatic Validation in Excel

Tags: regex, excel, validation, vba, vbscript

I'm currently having a data validation problem in Excel and may be the victim of "over-thinking" the problem.

My requirement is simple - I receive a large amount of xls files which all need to comply to an exact format.

For example, I need all of the files I receive to have have the following strings in cells A1 to A3: "FirstName", "LastName", "Email". (Case matters).

In reality, there are a lot more headers than this and trawling through every file and ensuring that all of the headings exist and are spelt correctly/in the correct case is very tedious and time consuming. I believe that it would be possible to create a module or tool in Visual Basic which could check the format and then return either correct/false based on whether the file complies with the required format.

I have looked into regular expressions (but believe that this may be overkill as I only require EXACT matches) and have no experience in using VB. I have looked online for help - some of which has been useful, some of which has be way too advanced for the tool I need.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following if you are using Windows:

1. Copy the code below into a file and name it with a *.vbs extension eg. "ExcelHeader.vbs", and save it somewhere eg. on your desktop
2. Put all your Excel files that you want to check headers with in a folder
3. Double-click the .vbs file, and select that folder when prompted

The script will then run through the folder and tell you which files are not conforming to your header requirements.

(you can also modify the code below to include more headers, it should be obvious from my comments below in the "Else If" part).

```
Dim sFolder, fso, files, folder, objExcel, objWorkbook

 sFolder = SelectFolder( "" )
 If sFolder = vbNull Then
     WScript.Echo "Cancelled"
 Else
     WScript.Echo "Selected Folder: """ & sFolder & """"
 End If

 ' use strPath to look for excel files list
 Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 Set folder = fso.GetFolder(sFolder)
 Set files = folder.Files

 Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

 For Each file In files

    Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(file)

' add more headers as you wish as ElseIf statements below

    If objExcel.Cells(1, 1).Value <> "FirstName" Then
        MsgBox(file & " is not correct.")
    ElseIf objExcel.Cells(1, 2).Value <> "LastName" Then
            MsgBox(file & " is not correct.")
    ElseIf objExcel.Cells(1, 3).Value <> "Email" Then
            MsgBox(file & " is not correct.")
    End If

    objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close(0)

Next

objExcel.Quit


 Function SelectFolder( myStartFolder )
 ' This function opens a "Select Folder" dialog and will
 ' return the fully qualified path of the selected folder
 '
 ' Argument:
 '     myStartFolder    [string]    the root folder where you can start browsing;
 '                                  if an empty string is used, browsing starts
 '                                  on the local computer
 '
 ' Returns:
 ' A string containing the fully qualified path of the selected folder
 '
 ' Written by Rob van der Woude
 ' http://www.robvanderwoude.com

     ' Standard housekeeping
     Dim objFolder, objItem, objShell

     ' Custom error handling
     On Error Resume Next
     SelectFolder = vbNull

     ' Create a dialog object
     Set objShell  = CreateObject( "Shell.Application" )
     Set objFolder = objShell.BrowseForFolder( 0, "Select Folder", 0, myStartFolder )

     ' Return the path of the selected folder
     If IsObject( objfolder ) Then SelectFolder = objFolder.Self.Path

     ' Standard housekeeping
     Set objFolder = Nothing
     Set objshell  = Nothing
     On Error Goto 0

 End Function

 Function ReadExcel( myXlsFile, mySheet, my1stCell, myLastCell, blnHeader )
' Function :  ReadExcel
' Version  :  2.00
' This function reads data from an Excel sheet without using MS-Office
'
' Arguments:
' myXlsFile   [string]   The path and file name of the Excel file
' mySheet     [string]   The name of the worksheet used (e.g. "Sheet1")
' my1stCell   [string]   The index of the first cell to be read (e.g. "A1")
' myLastCell  [string]   The index of the last cell to be read (e.g. "D100")
' blnHeader   [boolean]  True if the first row in the sheet is a header
'
' Returns:
' The values read from the Excel sheet are returned in a two-dimensional
' array; the first dimension holds the columns, the second dimension holds
' the rows read from the Excel sheet.
'
' Written by Rob van der Woude
' http://www.robvanderwoude.com
    Dim arrData( ), i, j
    Dim objExcel, objRS
    Dim strHeader, strRange

    Const adOpenForwardOnly = 0
    Const adOpenKeyset      = 1
    Const adOpenDynamic     = 2
    Const adOpenStatic      = 3

    ' Define header parameter string for Excel object
    If blnHeader Then
        strHeader = "HDR=YES;"
    Else
        strHeader = "HDR=NO;"
    End If

    ' Open the object for the Excel file
    Set objExcel = CreateObject( "ADODB.Connection" )
    ' IMEX=1 includes cell content of any format; tip by Thomas Willig
    objExcel.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & _
                  myXlsFile & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;IMEX=1;" & _
                  strHeader & """"

    ' Open a recordset object for the sheet and range
    Set objRS = CreateObject( "ADODB.Recordset" )
    strRange = mySheet & "$" & my1stCell & ":" & myLastCell
    objRS.Open "Select * from [" & strRange & "]", objExcel, adOpenStatic

    ' Read the data from the Excel sheet
    i = 0
    Do Until objRS.EOF
        ' Stop reading when an empty row is encountered in the Excel sheet
        If IsNull( objRS.Fields(0).Value ) Or Trim( objRS.Fields(0).Value ) = "" Then Exit Do
        ' Add a new row to the output array
        ReDim Preserve arrData( objRS.Fields.Count - 1, i )
        ' Copy the Excel sheet's row values to the array "row"
        ' IsNull test credits: Adriaan Westra
        For j = 0 To objRS.Fields.Count - 1
            If IsNull( objRS.Fields(j).Value ) Then
                arrData( j, i ) = ""
            Else
                arrData( j, i ) = Trim( objRS.Fields(j).Value )
            End If
        Next
        ' Move to the next row
        objRS.MoveNext
        ' Increment the array "row" number
        i = i + 1
    Loop

    ' Close the file and release the objects
    objRS.Close
    objExcel.Close
    Set objRS    = Nothing
    Set objExcel = Nothing

    ' Return the results
    ReadExcel = arrData
End Function
```

P.S. Thanks to Rob van der Woude for the bottom Function :)

Comment: A few suggested tweaks. The Excel Application should only be created once rather than for each file. It is worth testing that the file type is Excel before opening and for a large amount of xls files a report format is probably better than a msgbox for each issue

Comment: Yes thanks I am aware that creating the Excel API object everytime is a waste of computer resources, but for some reason the code wouldn't run when I moved that code out of the for loop.  The simple msgbox code is there for ease of use by the end user.  Anyway, on to other questions :)

Answer (score 1):

The code below

- Opens each Excel file in the folder specified by `strFolderName`
- Runs a single *case sensitive* test on the first three cells of the first sheet, and  writes all filenames and the test results to a csv file *"ErrReport.csv"* in the `strFolderName` directory with
  `objTF.writeline strFileName & "," & (StrComp(StrTest, strArray, vbBinaryCompare) = 0)`

  [image]

  ```
  Sub FileChk()
  Dim Wb As Workbook
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim objFSO As Object
  Dim objTF As Object
  Dim strFolderName As String
  Dim strFileName As String
  Dim strArray As String
  Dim StrTest As String

  strFolderName = "c:\temp\"
  strFileName = Dir(strFolderName & "*.xls*")
  strArray = Join(Array("FirstName", "LastName", "Email"), ",")        

  Set objFSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
  Set objTF = objFSO.createtextfile(strFolderName & "ErrReport.csv")

  With Application
      .DisplayAlerts = False
      .EnableEvents = False
      .ScreenUpdating = False
      lngCalc = .Calculation
      .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
  End With

  Do While Len(strFileName) > 0
      Set Wb = Workbooks.Open(strFolderName & strFileName)
      Set ws = Wb.Sheets(1)
      StrTest = Join(Application.Transpose(Range([ws].[a1], ws.[a3]).Value2), ",")
      objTF.writeline strFileName & "," & (StrComp(StrTest, strArray, vbBinaryCompare) = 0)
      Wb.Close False
      strFileName = Dir
  Loop

  With Application
      .CutCopyMode = False
      .DisplayAlerts = True
      .EnableEvents = True
      .ScreenUpdating = True
      .Calculation = lngCalc
  End With

  objTF.Close
  End Sub
  ```

Comment: @Rich just change `strFolderName = "c:\temp\"` to your directory - assuming all your files are in one place. Then run the code to produce the csv report in the same directory

Comment: How do I "run the code"? I am unable to get it to compile in Visual Basic Studio.

Comment: @Rich You had mentioned this as an Excel issue and tagged it VBA so I provided a VBA solurion to be run from Excel. I will convert it to a vbs later on.

Answer (score 0):

[vbs](/questions/tagged/vbs) answer below that gives the same output as the Excel VBA above. This version opens up the complete report when finished.

```
Dim objExcel
Dim objFSO
Dim objFolder
Dim objFile
Dim objTF
Dim Wb
Dim ws
Dim strFolderName
Dim strArray
Dim StrTest

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.application")
strFolderName = "c:\Temp"
strArray = Join(Array("FirstName", "LastName", "Email"), ",")

Set objFSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.getFolder(strFolderName)
Set objTF = objFSO.createtextfile(strFolderName & "ErrReport.csv")

With objExcel
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

On Error Resume Next
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
'If Right$(objFile.Name, Len(objFile.Name) - InStrRev(objFile.Name, ".")) Like "xls" Then
    If Right(objFile.Name, Len(objFile.Name) - InStrRev(objFile.Name, ".")) like "xls*" Then
        Set Wb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(objFile)
        Set ws = Wb.Sheets(1)
        StrTest = Join(objExcel.Transpose(ws.Range([ws].[a1], ws.[a3]).Value2), ",")
        objTF.writeline strFileName & "," & (StrComp(StrTest, strArray, vbBinaryCompare) = 0)
        Wb.Close False
    End If
Next
On Error GoTo 0

objTF.Close
With objExcel
    .DisplayAlerts = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .Workbooks.Open (strFolderName & "\ErrReport.csv")
    .Visible = True
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

## Overview

I started to comment on the VBA answer above, but decided a separate answer would be more clear. I started mainly to answer Rich's question "How do I implement/run this?" since this question was asked by someone with "no experience in using VB," and some respondents appear to be at that level also.

Here is how I would approach the problem: Put the file names either all in one folder, or list them on a **new** Excel master worksheet. Put the correct, canonical headings in that same master worksheet. Then put the code to check the other worksheets in this master worksheet. And finally, after checking the files, list whether they conform or not in that master worksheet.

### Step-by-step

1. Open a new Excel workbook to put your solution in. In this blank workbook, put in these items:

   - Correct **heading values** across the top, for example, in cells A1:X1.
   - The **filenames** of files to examine in a single column, for example, in cells A6:A60. Preferably, these file names should have the full path specified.
   - Leave the cells to the right of the filenames **empty**, as they will be overwritten with TRUE/FALSE values.
2. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to open the VBA editor, and find your new workbook in Project Explorer to the left.

   - If the Project Explorer pane is not visible, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to open it.
   - If you have multiple workbooks open, you'll need to find the VBAProject with the workbook's name after it in parentheses, for example, *VBAProject (Book1)*
   - If the lines are collapsed, click on the ***+*** sign to the left of *VBProject* to find the correct workbook.
3. **Right-click** on the *VBAProject* for that workbook, or any of the lines associated with it directly below, and select **Insert** -> **Module**. This should open a blank module area in the main section of the VBA editor.
4. Copy and paste the **Code** below into that blank module.
5. **Save** the workbook, either as a .xlsm, .xlsb, or .xls file (not .xlsx).
6. Go back to the worksheet (either press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> from the VBA editor, or just click on the spreadsheet), and **press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>**, then double-click on **FileCheck** to run the macro.
7. This will mark the files that conform to that header-pattern with TRUE to the right of the file name, and mark FALSE next to the files that do not conform.

### Code

```
#Const AllFilesInFolder = False
#Const SuppScreenUpdate = False             ' Suppress Screen Update

Sub FileCheck()
' Purpose: Verify header content on multiple specified files. Checks headers for each file:
'   1) Listed in this Workbook.Sheet(1) in the range specified by scFilesAddr -- OR --
'   2) All .xls* files in the folder/path specified by scFolderName
' Headers are matched to the values in the range specified by scHeaderAddr

    Dim IsFound As Boolean, DoMatch As Boolean
    Dim nFile As Long, nHeader As Long
    Dim Wkb As Workbook, wks As Worksheet
    Dim rngHdrMaster As Range, rngHdrTest As Range
    Dim rngFilenames As Range, sFileName As String
    #If SuppScreenUpdate Then
    Dim lngCalc As XlCalculation
    #End If

'         HEADERS' RANGE
' --> --> Change this Range address to the required matching headers <-- <--
    Const scHeaderAddr As String = "A1:C1"
    ' This range address should also match up with the headers in the worksheets to test!

    Set rngHdrMaster = ActiveSheet.Range(scHeaderAddr)

'         FILENAMES' RANGE
' --> --> Change this Range address to point to the File names to examine <-- <--
    Const scFilesAddr As String = "A6:A105"
    ' Ideally, all filenames listed should also list the full path, or be in the same
    ' folder as this workbook.

    Set rngFilenames = ActiveSheet.Range(scFilesAddr)
#If AllFilesInFolder Then           ' Get all Excel files in this folder
'         FOLDER PATH
' --> --> Change this Folder name to point to where all files will be examined
    Const scFolderName As String = "C:\Temp\"

    sFileName = Dir(strFolderName & "*.xls*")
    If Len(sFileName) > 0 Then
        sFileName = scFolderName & sFileName
        IsFound = True
    End If
#Else                               ' Get Excel files listed in master spreadsheet
    sFileName = rngFilenames(1).Value
    IsFound = (Len(Dir(sFileName)) > 0)
#End If
    nFile = 1

    #If SuppScreenUpdate Then           ' Optional: Set to True above if it runs slowly
    With Application
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        lngCalc = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With
    #End If

    Do While Len(sFileName) > 0     ' If Filename is specified, but File doesn't exist, just
        If IsFound Then             ' skip that file. If Filename is blank, then exit proc.
            Set Wkb = Workbooks.Open(sFileName)
            Set wks = Wkb.Sheets(1)
            Set rngHdrTest = wks.Range(scHeaderAddr)
            DoMatch = True
            For nHeader = 1 To rngHdrMaster.Columns.Count
                If rngHdrMaster(nHeader).Value2 <> rngHdrTest(nHeader).Value2 Then
                    DoMatch = False
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
            Wkb.Close False

            rngFilenames(nFile, 1).HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
            rngFilenames(nFile, 1).Value = sFileName
            rngFilenames(nFile, 2).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            rngFilenames(nFile, 2).Value = DoMatch              'Could also put Y/N here
            nFile = nFile + 1
            #If AllFilesInFolder Then
                sFileName = Dir()       ' Get next file infolder
            #Else           ' Put value in nFile row, 2nd col - rngFilenames can be 1 col wide.
                ' Uncomment code below to ensure it does not read past specified range
                ' Otherwise, will keep reading values until it finds empty cell-maybe desired?
                'If nFile > ActiveSheet.Range(scFilesAddr).Rows.Count Then
                '    Exit For
                'Else
                    sFileName = rngFilenames(nFile).Value
                    IsFound = (Len(Dir(sFileName)) > 0)
                '    If sFileName = "" Then sFileName = "None"
                'End If
            #End If
        End If
    Loop

    #If SuppScreenUpdate Then
    With Application
        .CutCopyMode = False
        .DisplayAlerts = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = lngCalc
    End With
    #End If

End Sub             ' FileCheck
```

### Setup

There are some ranges in the code you will have to define:

- For each heading you want compared, you'll need to have entered in the master spreadsheet. Then you'll also need to make sure the range address for those headings is entered in the scHeaderAddr constant. For example, if you had 5 headings, you would change the line like this:
  `Const scHeaderAddr As String = "A1:E1"`
- If you have more than 100 files that need to be compared, change the scFilesAddr constant to a range in a single column with the correct number of cells. 
  `Const scFilesAddr As String = "A6:A105"`
  See also *Selecting Filenames* under ***Customization*** below.
- If you'd rather examine all the Excel files in a folder, see the *Examine all files in a folder* section under ***Customization*** below. You'll also need to change the constant *scFolderName* to the path where these files can be found.

  `Const scFolderName As String = "C:\Temp\"`  '**Make sure it ends with a backslash!**

### Customization

#### Examine all files in a folder

There are some compiler constants in the code, which is kind of an advanced feature, but it makes it really easy to customize. If you want to examine all the files in the folder, just change the line at the top of the code to `#Const AllFilesInFolder = True`

Basically, when `AllFilesInFolder = True`, anything that is between `#If AllFilesInFolder Then` ... and ... `#Else` (or ... `#End If`, if `#Else` is missing) will be **run**, and anything between the `#Else` ... and ... `#End If` will be **ignored**. ***Or*** *vice-versa*, when it is `False`, anything that is between `#If AllFilesInFolder Then` ... and ... `#Else` will be **ignored**, and anything between the `#Else` ... and ... `#End If` will be **run**.

#### Suppress Screen Update

If it's running slowly with the opening of files, etc. change the line near the top to `#Const SuppScreenUpdate = True`. I put it in there because brettdj included it in his code, but it sometimes gets in the way of troubleshooting.

#### Restrict filenames to range

One final customization: The current functionality will start with the first cell in the range ***scFilesAddr***, continue down the column and quit when it finds the first **blank cell**, whether inside or outside the range. So technically, if you forgot to expand the range, it will still find over 100 filenames, as long as there is not a blank cell between them. If you'd rather have **each cell in the range be examined for a filename**, whether or not there is an intervening blank cell, remove the initial single-quotes (that *comment out*) from the beginning of lines 132-138 (beginning with `'If nFile > ActiveSheet.Range(scFilesAddr).Rows.Count Then` and ending with `'End If`).

By the way, it does check to see if the file exists, and any non-existent files will be ignored, but it will not stop the process.